# ¿Como hago para que me ponga la frase completa en java?

Tags: java, string

Tengo esto, ahora tendría que hacer un acumulador de todas las palabras de la cadena para que al final me las ponga en una frase seguida, pero me sale solo la ultima palabra.

Enunciado: Pide al usuario un número de palabras, una vez que se introducidas todas las palabras, se deben mostrar todas juntas en una misma frase.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal_5_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        //Variables
        int palabras=0;
        String cadena = new String();
        String suma ;
        
        System.out.println("Inserte el numero de palabras que quieres introducir: ");
        palabras= teclado.nextInt();
        
        
        System.out.println("Inserte " + palabras + " palabras");
        
        for(int i=0; i<=palabras;i++) {
            cadena= teclado.nextLine();}
            
            suma= suma + cadena;
        {
                
                
                System.out.println(suma);
        
            }
        
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente te liaste con las llaves en el bucle `for` . Mira :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Variables
    int palabras = 0;
    String cadena = new String();
    String suma = "";

    System.out.println("Inserte el numero de palabras que quieres introducir: ");
    palabras = teclado.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Inserte " + palabras + " palabras");

    for (int i = 0; i <= palabras; i++) {
        cadena = teclado.nextLine();
        suma = suma + cadena;
    }

    System.out.println(suma);

}
```

Saludos !!